# Java for loop executed twice

Tags: java

I am experiencing some troubles when executing a for loop. The loop is called twice. Here is the code that does the work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PoolItemMapper {
    public  List<Item> mapJsonObjectsToItems(JsonResponse jsonResponse) {
        int count = 0;
        List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
         List<Item> js = jsonResponse.getItems();
        for (Item item : jsonResponse.getItems()) {
            itemsList.add(addNormalItemProperties(item, new Item()));
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Call count: " + count);
        return itemsList;
    }

    private  Item addNormalItemProperties(Item oldItem, Item newItem) {
        if(oldItem.getMembersReference().getItems().size() <=  0) {
            return oldItem;
        } else if (oldItem.getMembersReference().getItems().size() > 0) {
            for (SubItem subItem: oldItem.getMembersReference().getItems()) {
                oldItem.getSubItems().add(creteNewSubItem(subItem));
            }
        }
        return oldItem;
    }

    private  Item creteNewSubItem(SubItem oldItem) {
        Item i = new Item();
        i.setDynamicRatio(oldItem.getDynamicRatio());
        i.setEphermal(oldItem.getEphermal());
        i.setInheritProfile(oldItem.getInheritProfile());
        i.setLogging(oldItem.getLogging());
        i.setRateLimit(oldItem.getRateLimit());
        i.setRatio(oldItem.getRatio());
        i.setSession(oldItem.getSession());
        i.setAddress(oldItem.getAddress());
        i.setName(oldItem.getName());
        i.setState(oldItem.getState());

        return i;
    }

}
```

The list has a size of 134, so I receive an output of two times 'Call count 134'. This results in having duplicates in the list.
Here are the POJOs:

JSON response where `getItems()` for the foor loop is called:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private String kind;
    private String selfLink;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public JsonResponse() {

    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getSelfLink() {
        return selfLink;
    }

    public void setSelfLink(String selfLink) {
        this.selfLink = selfLink;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

The `Item` class is a simple DTO, containing only variables and their getters/setters:
Here is where the method is invoked:

```
itemTree = new PoolTreeBuilderImpl().buildTree(j);

itemTree.stream().forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println("[PARENT] " + i.getData().toString());
    i.getData().getSubItems().stream().forEach(si -> {
        System.out.println("       [CHILD] " + si.toString());
    });
});
```

}

and the `PoolTreeBuilderImpl` calls:

```
@Override
public List<TreeNode<Item>> buildTree(JsonResponse jsonResponse) {
    List<TreeNode<Item>> itemTree = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Item> mappedItems = new PoolItemMapper().mapJsonObjectsToItems(jsonResponse);
    for (Item i : mappedItems) {
        TreeNode<Item> item = new TreeNode<>(i);
        if (i.getSubItems().size() > 0) {
            for (Item subItem : i.getSubItems()) {
                item.addChild(subItem);
            }
        }
        itemTree.add(item);
    }
    return itemTree;
}
```

Could someone explain me why this loop is called twice resulting in having each subitem twice in the list?

**Update**
When executing this code, I don't have the duplicates:

```
List<Item> mappedItems = new PoolItemMapper().mapJsonObjectsToItems(jsonResponse);
mappedItems.forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println("[PARENT] " + i.toString());
    i.getMembersReference().getItems().forEach(s -> {
        System.out.println("      [CHILD] " + s.toString());
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats the expected execution count?

Comment: the expectation is that the loop is only called once

Comment: How many times `buildTree` called?

Comment: What is the size of `jsonResponse.getItems()`. Seems like you just receive too many items

Comment: How many times `itemTree = new PoolTreeBuilderImpl().buildTree(j);` that is invoked..

Comment: it is only called once, thats why I am so confused

Comment: I think I found the problem. I call the method twice (one times by calling the TreeBuilder which calls it internally) and then calling it explicizty myself. This results in working on exisiting objects that already contain a 'valid' subItem list

Comment: Off topic but the second parameter for `addNormalItemProperties` is never used so you are creating a new object unnecessarily each time you call it.

Comment: see my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `JsonResponse` object, which is always the same. The objects within the JsonResponse list are modified twice, so there are duplicates. That is why (@Joakim Danielson) there is the second parameter `newItem`.
Additionally I had to change the signature of the `buildTree` method of the TreeBuilder to accept a list of `Item`s, the one returned by the mapper.

Comment: It's great if you've solved your problem but it is irrelevant to my comment since the second parameter isn't used inside that method.

Comment: But thats what the parameter was supposed for:)

Comment: You are creating an object and then you never use it but if that is what you want...

Comment: the object was supposed to be created, so i create a new object instead of modifying the old one each time

Comment: But you are never using it so it is pointless, read your own code. End of discussion from my part.